# The following puzzle has no description

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Admittedly, this one is fairly easy... I hope it isn't too bad. Whether it is bad or not is up to you.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ad80fcl.png]

Comment: It seems there is another imgur link hidden in blue color. But, I am not able to read it in its written form.

Comment: You're right. But is there a way to find it? Hint: It's not pure white so it can be differentiated. If only you could change the white background....

Comment: Wow this is creepy, I can see the hidden text directly on the image from the post. Depending on what angle I move my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial:
First "hidden" message in first picture leads to:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l3XT.png

Second message leads to:

> not c4M5fvz5, but look at colors in first sentence. That makes f5zMv54c.
>  http://pastebin.com/f5zMv54c

Third message:

> use ASCII OCT table
>  document/d/1xW6YdNa31SoeGpUSWfz4jdpxYAJrs3v77XhwAzlzsQk

4th step:

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xW6YdNa31SoeGpUSWfz4jdpxYAJrs3v77XhwAzlzsQk/edit

5th step:

> Message is hidden in "not so empty" rows.
>  something like
>  http://gdforum.freeforums.net/thread/40679/subject
>  + message: It’s somewhere there… ;)
>  but "You do not have permission to access this thread."
>  So thread exists, but no idea how to get there…

Comment: How did you find the pastebin link? :-/

Comment: look at colors at 1st line… got it? :)

Comment: @JanIvan Could you outline *(\*cough\*)* the method of getting from 4 to 5?  I hope OP provides us a path around the permissions issue.

Comment: I can open docs, can't open 5th one. 4th one is stego. But i use "reverse colors" addon, so i read white text on black window. Or maybe try ctrl+A

Comment: I got it but I was asking you to add how you found it. Like to go from 3rd to 4th you need to convert Octal to Text. Everyone should understand how you solved it. :)

Comment: I know, i will add details later :) I like to let ppl to solve easy things

Comment: that part was broken :\ whatever you got it because the last step is trivial :P

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

The first image,

> when equalized:
>   [image]

reveals the link for the second image:

> [image]

However,

> [http://imgur.com/c4M5fvz5](https://imgur.com/c4M5fvz5) and [http://imgur.com/c4M5fv25](https://imgur.com/c4M5fv25) don't lead anywhere

Comment: I think the second one might be a Pastebin link, not an Imgur link.